# Why i'm getting error while running andriod app on phone?

Tags: android

I have written some code in Android for my first learning application. When I run the app for testing from the android studio while compiling I get this error can anyone help me out with this problem?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.firstapp.myapp, PID: 29586
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firstapp.myapp/com.firstapp.myapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3931)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2356)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8315)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at com.firstapp.myapp.HomeActivity.init(HomeActivity.java:69)
        at com.firstapp.myapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3732)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3931) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8315) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29586 SIG: 9
```

I have figured out that only this code is generating this error if i remove this code and then run the application it works fine. (e.g. other activites)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/mainBg"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@color/primaryDark">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_header_bg"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            

            <!-- Card item row -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/galBtn">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/gallery"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="@string/gallery"
                            android:textColor="@color/home_btn_txt"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"  />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
                            app:tint="@color/home_right_arrow_color"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

               



            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The stacktrace gives you a very specific reason and location: `java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at com.firstapp.myapp.HomeActivity.init(HomeActivity.java:69)`. We have no idea what you're doing there since you haven't shown us any of your code, but whatever it is you need to fix it.

Comment: Please check the question again I have edited the question and added the code that is generating this error. Thanks